# How to turn the update function back on

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When my menu is open, I want the Update function to be disabled, in the Update function I have this if statement

```
if(originalTime <= 0 && endGame)
{
    menu.SetActive(true);
    endGame = false;
    enabled = false;
}
```

That shows the main menu and stops any updates from happening.  What I want is a way to restart the update function

```
public void KeepPlaying()
{
    originalTime = 3;
    endGame = true;
    menu.SetActive(false);
    enabled = true;
    Update();
    //Debug.Log(endGame);
    //Debug.Log(originalTime);
}
```

`enabled = true;` doesn't seem to restart the update function

Comment: The question is not clear to me. You should clarify the terms(what is `enabled`, `Update` function etc..) a bit.

Comment: why are you re-setting originalTime?  You also should just create a 3rd "paused" variable and cut out all the nonsense.  Also... You need to place a breakpoint in keepplaying.  As far as anyone knows, you're never calling it.

Comment: If you setactive(false) update doesnt run, you would need to turn it back on.

Comment: when you do `menu.SetActive(false);` it sounds like the menu which `Update` should be called is deactivated ... `Update` is not called on deactivated GameObjects ...